# Reveal markers around a selected location on Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am currently coding on Android Studio for Google Maps.

I made the search function working based on the text searched on the search bar. And once the user presses "Search" the map will zoom into that selected location and place a coloured marker.

However, I would like to do it like this:

Once you select the location, you will reveal several markers based on a certain radius/ certain area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the markers to your map as invisible and compute the distance between your desired location and each marker to show those nearer than a given distance.

```
private List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>(); // List to hold your markers
```

Add the markers to the map and to the list:

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(yourPosition).visible(false));
markers.add(marker);
```

And then create a function that, given a `LatLng` computes the distance to each marker (I'm using `SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween` from the [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/)) and shows the desired markers:

```
private void showMarkers(LatLng location, float distance) {
    for(Marker marker : markers) {
        if (SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(marker.getPosition(), location) <= distance) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```